# How to update item inside an embedded array without adding a new item in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

For example, I have arrays embedded inside array `[["A", 4], ["B", 5]]`, and I would like to update the element inside the first embedded array so that the final outcome because `[["A", 5], ["B", 5]]`, and not `[["A", 4], ["B", 5], ["A", 5]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before replace value of your array make sure you have `NSMutableArray` *(mutable)* ?
Otherwise you get error:

Yes i have `NSMutableArray` then follow my suggestion: *(Here i give simple basic logic)*

For replace any value at specific Index of `NSMutableArray`, Use[`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABBBECB).

For Example

```
[MyArrayName replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:MyValues];
```

Apply this logic:

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful way to get started!